# Выборка JpaRepostiory Query

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Предположим у меня такой запрос

```
@Query("select avg(ev.evaluation) from Evaluation ev group by ev.studentId")
public List<Integer> listAvgEvaluationByStudentId();
```

Делается выборка среднего бала с группировкой по id студента.

Но мне нужно помимо самого балла, прикрутить к нему id студента, выглядеть запрос будет так.

```
@Query("select ev.studentId, avg(ev.evaluation) from Evaluation ev group by ev.studentId")
public ... listAvgEvaluationByStudentId();
```

Не могу только понять, какой тип вернётся и во что поступающие данные обернуть. Помогите с типом возвращаемого результата.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вернётся список массивов объектов - `List<Object[]>`.

Comment: Все верно. Благодарю.